# Download from Google Drive using OAuth2

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to download from Google Drive using OAuth2, but I am unable to authenticate url.

I get the following error:

> 2013-08-21 21:22:39.569 LoudCloud[4790:c07] Authorization
>   successful... 2013-08-21 21:22:40.262 LoudCloud[4790:c07] Error: Error
>   Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1011 "Expected status code in
>   (200-299), got 401" UserInfo=0x98b90f0
>   {AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey=https://doc-0k-bg-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/6gj8c1544p7s7pniqjbc4mq6j0fb056i/8bj1nr5shkpsku5m0mde1rr8v7n975ll/1377108000000/00742820994415136760/00742820994415136760/0B0kZ8xc_ZGhbWnZOQUVuTGtObjA?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true>,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://doc-0k-bg-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/6gj8c1544p7s7pniqjbc4mq6j0fb056i/8bj1nr5shkpsku5m0mde1rr8v7n975ll/1377108000000/00742820994415136760/00742820994415136760/0B0kZ8xc_ZGhbWnZOQUVuTGtObjA?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code in (200-299), got 401,
>   AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=}

CODE:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth =
        [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                              clientID:kClientID
                                                          clientSecret:kClientSecret];

        NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [auth authorizeRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error == nil) {
                NSLog(@"Authorization successful...");
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Authorization failed...");
            }
        }];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:req];

        op.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

        [op setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
            float percentage = ((float)((int)totalBytesRead) / (float)((int)totalBytesExpectedToRead)) * 100.0;

            NSLog(@"Download percentage: %f", percentage);
        }];

        [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];

        [op start];
```